# Index and match but have duplicate text values

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I am trying to create an index and match formula on a spreadsheet, however my data in the left column has identical names in this column (This is due to this being a different part in a different device). Is there a way I can get this to identify between the two parts?

[image: spreadsheet]

Comment: You can get an "nth" match, but would this help you? The way to distinquish the two equally named parts are really the part numbers. On a first glance I'd restructure your data to `INDEX` and `MATCH` on this unique numbers rather than "Part". Your data might not cater for this though.

Comment: I don't think my data would cater for this also. I believe I may need to edit how the data is  laid out (By putting each device next to the part also and adding an if statement for each, however the formula is going to be long.

Answer (score 0):

In `E2`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(H:H,AGGREGATE(15,6, ROW(G$3:G$17)/(G$3:G$17=D2),COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2))),"")
```

[image]